# Closed form for a conditional trigonometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, closed-form, trigonometric-series

Do you know an easy way to prove the following $\forall~L$?
$\sum\limits_{\scriptstyle k = 1,~k \ne L\atop
\scriptstyle ~l = 1,~l \ne L}^N {\cos \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{N}n(k -
l)} \right)}  - 2\sum\limits_{k = 1,~k \ne L}^N {\cos \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{N}n(k
- L)} \right)}  + 1 = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{(N - 2)^2}{\rm{~~if~}}n = 0\\
4{\rm{~~~if~}}n \ne 0
\end{array} \right.$

All parameters are integer numbers.

Comment: Incorporate back the terms associated to $k=L$ and $l=L$, then exploit $\cos\theta=\text{Re}(e^{i\theta})$ and the formula for the sum of geometric progressions.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I like Jack D'Aurizio 's approach. This question comes from here: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878067/proof-that-certain-sums-of-complex-numbers-in-a-unitary-matrix-produce-the-sam](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878067/proof-that-certain-sums-of-complex-numbers-in-a-unitary-matrix-produce-the-sam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for $n=0$ we have
$$ (N-1)^2-2(N-1)+1  =(N-2)^2 $$

If $n\ne0$ , using the symmetry $ \cos(\pi - x) = -\cos(x)$ (or any other method) you should be able to convince yourself that
$$   \sum\limits_{k = 1}^N {\cos \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{N}n(k
- L)} \right)} =0 
$$
For all integers $N, L, n \ne 0$.

So 
$$\sum\limits_{k = 1,~k \ne L}^N {\cos \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{N}n(k
- L)} \right)} = 0 -  {\cos \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{N}n(L
- L)} \right)} =-1
$$
And
$$\sum\limits_{\scriptstyle k = 1,~k \ne L\atop
\scriptstyle ~l = 1,~l \ne L}^N {\cos \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{N}n(k -
l)} \right)}
\\ = \sum\limits_{\scriptstyle k = 1,~k \ne L}^N { - \cos \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{N}n(k -
L)} \right)}
\\ = {\cos \left( {\frac{{2\pi }}{N}n(L
- L)} \right)}
=1$$